# selecting an element after adding a new class is not working

Tags: class, jquery-selectors

I'm having a link which will be clicked only once. So I'm adding a class to the link to verify that it's been clicked and prevent the user from clicking it again.

```
<a href="#" id="plus">my link</a>

$("a#plus[class!='clicked']").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

so after clicking on the link a class 'clicked' will be added to the link and if the user clicks again this should happen

```
$("a#plus.clicked").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked before');
});
```

but the result is executing the first block of code though the class 'clicked has been added here's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gkwym8nr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handlers are attached to the elements that matched *at the time `on()` was called*. Adding / removing classes later doesn't move or replace the handlers. You'll want to use event delegation to catch the events based on currently-matching elements.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "a#plus[class!='clicked']", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("span.result").text('link clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

$(document.body).on('click', "a#plus.clicked", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("span.result").text(' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="plus">link</a>
<span class="result"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Here's the working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gkwym8nr/10/